# A paradoxical stochastic process?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value, stochastic-processes

Consider a single die that has 6 faces numbered 1,2,3,4,5,6 each side being equally likely. Roll the die until the first 6 occurs, if all the rolls prior to the 6 were even, what is the expected length of the number of rolls required until you stop?

Comment: > if all the rolls prior to the 6 were even

Does that mean you're restricting the outcome space to only {2,4}

Comment: What happens if my first roll is 1?  Then I can never satisfy the stopping criterion you've given...

Comment: if an odd number is rolled assume the process starts again and this roll is not counted.

Comment: @Tilefish -> the outcome space is all 6 numbers but we only count the number of outcomes of even numbers. Note this means {2,4} AND {6} are all counted in the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that all rolls prior to the 6 are even, I assume this means we can only roll 2,4 and 6. If we want number of successes before the first failure, this just follows a negative binomial (1,p). Now from the first assumption $p=2/3$, therefore the expected value is $2$.

Comment: I'd interpret the question as asking for the number of trials to the third success ("*what is the expected length of the number of rolls required until you stop*"), not the number of failures, since you don't stop until *after* you see a 6. This would increase the expected value by $1$.

Comment: It could be, though, that if you get an odd, you stop, otherwise, you stop when you get a 6.  So you stop on a 1,3,5, or 6.  Then all the rolls prior to stopping were even.  It is not a well-worded question, as it does say "each side being equally likely", which lets out 1, 3, and 5 having probability 0, but doesn't explain how you ever stop if you get an odd.

Comment: safe to assume you start process all over again and the roll is not counted in a length.

Comment: @LucasRoberts Okay then I think my solution, with glen_b's addition if you include the failure count, should be correct